# Set a Value in a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to search for a file on Window Path. So I've created a loop and for each directory I look for my File. If Found I Raise a flag.

My file sofar:

```
    @Echo OFF
SET path=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
SET /A var=0

for %%G in ("%path:;=" "%") do IF EXIST 7x.exe (SET /A var = 1   )

IF /I "%var%" EQU "1" ECHO equality with 1
IF /I "%var%" EQU "0" ECHO equality with 0
```

But my variable are 0 after my loop even though I know for sure the file is there.

So this raises some questions:
1) How do I set my variable var inside the loop
2) Can I test for the value of var before checking for the existance of a file 
   Pseudo code: `If (var == 0 && EXIST 7x.exe) set var = 1`

Comment: So you want to check if 7z.exe is present in your path? Why don't you simply try to run it?

Comment: Because i want to display an error message if it doesn't

Comment: why not just do `where 7zip.exe & echo %errorlevel%`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard my problem is I don't know much batch scripting. So if there is an smarter solution please show me

Comment: I was about to, so there @Stephan showed exactly how :)

Comment: You forgot to include the `%%G` FOR parameter in the file name: `for %%G in ("%path:;=" "%") do IF EXIST "%%~G\7x.exe" (SET /A var = 1   )`

Comment: @Aacini that didn't help. Can you try to create a complete solution for me?

Comment: Of course that this should work... I suggest you to change the `IF EXIST "%%~G\7x.exe" (SET /A var = 1 )` part by a simple `ECHO "%%~G\7x.exe"` so you can confirm what exactly is being processed...

Comment: (by the way: it's `7z.exe`, not `7x.exe`)

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, exactly as in my above comment posted 13 minutes ago...

Comment: @Stephan: You posted _the exact same code_ that I have posted 13 minutes before just two comments above. I still don't understand why...

Comment: @Aacini yeah - you made your point clear, and I already deleted the comment in question together with other comments only related to this conversation. Let's stop it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `where` command (by default) searches a file through the path (it can also be used to search a folder tree or even the whole disk with the `/R` switch, which you obviously don't need here). It returns an errorlevel of `0` if the file was found and `1` if not found. There is even a `/Q` (Quiet) switch. So this makes it quite easy:

```
where /q 7z.exe 
set var=%errorlevel%
echo equality with %var%
```

Instead of the `set` command, you can also directly `echo equality with %errorlevel%`, but keep in mind, using (nearly) any command between `where` and the use of `%errorlevel%` might change the errorlevel.

Comment: Thx I'll Try it out. If you have the time then for educational purposes. Can you create a solution "my! way

Comment: @Stephan I think you should put an `if` here which would check `errorlevel` variable. For example: `if "%errorlevel%" EQU "0" do something`.

Comment: I dont understand your solution %var% allways equals tio 1 nomatter what I'm searching for

Comment: @double-beep: OP does obviously know, how to build an `if` statement - his question was how to check, if the file exists

Comment: @JensBorrisholt: working fine here.  Do you have the code inside a command block?

Comment: @Stephan sorry :-).

@Stephan as because he had posted the src code including the `if` statement.

Comment: Will someone please show a complete example. I have still no idea of how to use it

Comment: @JensBorrisholt `where /q /r` searches the current working folder and it's subfolders for the file. OP want to check, if it's within `%path%`, so without `/r`